# How to make array from MySQL ROW type?

Tags: mysql, d, variant

I am using [mysql-native driver](http://code.dlang.org/packages/mysql-native). My code:

```
ResultRange MySQLTablesRange = mysqlconnection.query(`SELECT historysensor FROM TableName`);
auto historysensor = MySQLTablesRange.array.filter!(a=>a[0].coerce!string.canFind("historysensor"));
```

But on send string I am getting to `historysensor` not an array, but structure like: `Row([historysensor_10774], [false])`. 
So every time to get value I need to do a lot of casting like:

```
foreach(sensor;historysensor)
{
    writeln(sensor[0].coerce!string.split("_")[1]);
}
```

How I can make `historysensor` as simple array, to be able to work without `[0].coerce!string`?

Comment: yuou that `.array` you have in there is useless. If you want that, stick it at the end.

Comment: Adam, for my regret without `.array` do not getting any result :( I do not know why :(
I tried also `auto historysensor = MySQLTablesRange.array.filter!(a=>a[0].coerce!string.canFind("historysensor")).array;` but still getting `Row` data type as result.

Comment: Do you loop over it right after making the call or is there some other query or something in the middle?

Comment: Ugh I hate edits. But of course you'll get Row as a result, that's what the range returns, you'd have to `map` or something to pull an individual row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just map it before doing the other stuff

```
auto historysensor = MySQLTablesRange.array.
   map!(a => a[0].coerce!string). // this is new
   filter!(a.canFind("historysensor"). // no need for coerce here now
   array; // convert to plain array of strings
```

BTW using `filter` here is probably a mistake too, make that part of your query so the database does it, that would be likely more efficient and easier to read.

Comment: Big thanks Adam! As always you have perfect solutions!